# compute an integral $\int {\frac{dx}{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}}$

Tags: integration

How we can compute this integral:

$$\int {\frac{dx}{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}}$$

i know that the solution is:

$$I=\frac{2 (x-2)}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $\displaystyle t=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}{x-1}$ to get $x=\dfrac{t^2-2}{t^2-1}$ and $dx=\dfrac{2t}{(1-t^2)^2}dt$;  then

$\displaystyle\int {\frac{dx}{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}}=\int\frac{1}{\frac{1}{(1-t^2)^2}\cdot t}\cdot\frac{2t}{(1-t^2)^2} dt=2\int dt=2t+C$

$\displaystyle=\frac{2\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}{x-1}+C=\frac{2(x-2)}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}+C$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

As $x^2-3x+2=\dfrac{(2x-3)^2-1}4$

set $2x-3=\sec\theta$  where $0\le\theta\le\pi,\implies \tan\dfrac\theta2\ge0$

to find $I=2\tan\dfrac\theta2+K$

Finally $$\tan\dfrac\theta2=+\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$x^2-3x+2=(x-1)(x-2)$. Substituting $t=x-1$, we have $\displaystyle\int\frac{dt}{t\sqrt{t~(t-1)}}$. Then let either

$t=\cosh^2u~$ or $~t=\sec^2v$. The latter will yield $\displaystyle\int2\cos v~dv$, which is trivial.